# Find preprocessor values from compiled executable

Tags: c++, linux, gnu, tar

**Stack**

- OS: Linux 3.14.26
- Language: C++
- Framework: Qt 5.5.1
- Compiler: gnu

**Background**

An application I'm working on allows the user to revert to a former software version backup. The backups are stored on the device (running on linux) in .tar archives. Within the archives is the executable (executable/x-application). However, when it lists the backups, it lists them by date, not by their version. I've been tasked with finding a way to display the associated software version along with the dates of the backups on the UI.

**Problem**

I cannot find the version number in the app's executable. In the source code, we define it with preprocessor `#define` directives. I'd like to do it this way because I'd like it to be backwards compatible, without having to introduce new code that would add the version number to a separate, non-source code file in the directory.

**What I've Tried**

I have tried using the `tar` utility in combination with several other filtering and transforming commands. I've used `grep` and `sed` to filter out only the executable file within the archive, and run `tar -xOf <archive> <executable_name>` to output the contents of the executable into `stdout`. While the output does show the variable *names*, it does not show their respective values along with them.

If our version is defined as so in the source `#define VERSION "x.x.x"`, and later used in a variable in the code `versionText`,
then the output of `tar -xOf <archive> <executable> | strings | grep -i "version"` yields:

```
versionText
```

where the output has the variable name, but no associated value.

---

Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible? To find values defined as a `#define` directive in the source code after compilation? Would a decompiler work for this case? What other ways might I accomplish this without moving on to just making the version saved to a separate, non-source code file in the directory?

Comment: I don't think those are included as `#define` is generally just a glorified find replace function, but someone might be able to correct me

Comment: Since macros are textually replaced before compilation, this is impossible in general. You might be able to extract the version somehow from the places where the macro is used, but it might be tricky.

Comment: It very much depends on the code.  `#define` will not put _anything_ in your compiled binary.  It merely (potentially) modifies the source code.  What you are asking is - _"Does my code store this value somewhere?"_. I can't say if it does.

Comment: Instead of trying to hack together a solution, modify the backup storage to include versions.

Comment: `we define it with preprocessor #define directives` Do you do anything with that `#define`, or is it just unused?

Comment: @KamilCuk We do use it throughout the code. Variables in the code associated with its value are shown by name when I read the executable to `stdout`, but no values are shown next to them or the lines after them.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Making it include the versions going forward would be easy, but I was asked to investigate a solution to find the version from the pre-existing format first before implementing anything additional.

Comment: `We do use it throughout the code.` How do you use it? `value are shown by name` The important part is, is the version in the output of `strings ./executable`? Is there anything unique.

Comment: @KamilCuk The executable is held within an `.tar` archive on the device. Can I pipe the output of `tar -xOf` into `strings` somehow? It would be ideal to avoid extracting anything from the archive for the solution if not necessary.

Comment: Well, `tar -xOf file | strings`. (But tbh, if the archive is not compressed, I wonder if just `strings file.tar` would work, but I don't know). Strings is incredibly simple program - it just goes through all the bytes in the file and outputs all printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Do you define the version _number_ as a macro or do you define a string with the version? How _exactly_ do you use that string/number? What functions do you call? Where are they passed? Please post an example code - please post an [MCVE].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236975/discussion-between-xonu-and-kamilcuk).

Answer (score 1):

You could use an old facility from the RCS versioning system. Put the version in an `RCS` string that you compile into your program. Example:

###### version.h

```
static char const rcsid[] = "$Revision: 1.4 $";
```

###### program.cpp

```
#include "version.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << rcsid << '\n';
}
```

Now compile your program and run `ident program` and you may see something like this:

```
     $Revision: 1.4 $
     $Revision: 1.4 $
```

Do `ident program | sort -u` to filter out duplicates.

Full list of RCS keywords you could use:

- `$Author$` The login name of the user who checked in the revision.
- `$Date$` The date and time the revision was checked in.
- `$Header$` A standard header containing the full RCS file name, the revision number, the date and time, the author, the state, and the locker (if locked).
- `$Id$` Same as `$Header$`, except that the RCS file name is without directory components.
- `$Locker$` The login name of the user who locked the revision (empty if not locked).
- `$Log$` The log message supplied during checkin.  For `ident`'s purposes, this is equivalent to `$RCSfile$`.
- `$Name$` The symbolic name used to check out the revision, if any.
- `$RCSfile$` The RCS file name without directory components.
- `$Revision$` The revision number assigned to the revision.
- `$Source$` The full RCS file name.
- `$State$` The state assigned to the revision with the `-s` option of `rcs(1)` or `ci(1)`.